# Не обновляются стили Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, кэширование, css

Есть блог на Wordpress 3.2.1 Возникла ситуация когда после изменения файла стилей в шаблоне стили на блоге не изменились. Плагины кэширования не используются, кэш браузера чистил несколько раз, не помогает, рестарт сервера тоже не помог. Ради эксперимента удалил css файл с сервера, старые стили по прежнему отображаются. Кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой подскажите, как её решить. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: А вы не пробовали смотреть в браузере, какие стили срабатывают и в каких файлах они находятся?

Comment: Естественно пробовал. Но дело не в этом. Даже при полном удалении css файла дизайн сайта не изменяется, при просмотре исходного кода в браузере файл стилей отображается и читается, хотя реально его на сервере нет. Я понимаю, что дело в кэше, но Wordpress по умолчанию не кэширует файлы сайтов. Дело скорее всего в кэшировании сервера. Но хостер утверждает, что отключил кэш и перезагрузил сервер. Где искать причину в такой ситуации даже не знаю.

Answer (score 5):

Не надо ждать. Скорее всего у вас в `htaccess` стоит кэширование для браузеров. Для того чтобы браузер понял что стиль другой просто поставте в загрузке стиля в шаблоне после названия файла знак вопроса и какаой-то параметр обычно я ставлю число. получается так:
было

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie6.css"/>
```

стало

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie6.css?1"/>
```

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/ie6.css?1"/>

этот вариант реально мне помог,
спасибо автору за полезную информацию! ;-)
С наступающим всех Новым Годом!:-)

Answer (score 1):

Я вообще убрал версию в файле стилей через подключение стилей в `functions.php`, указав `null` третьим параметром.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'child_style', trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array( 'parent_style' ), null );
```

Можно указать свою версию вместо `null`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй подождать. У меня один полдня-день примерно уходит чтобы CSS обновился и стал нормально отображаться.

Так же чтобы проверить чтобы нормально всё отображалось, можешь попробывать использовать серверы через которые видно как ваш сайт виден на других браузерах.

А как решить саму проблему, чтобы обновлялось сразу я не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Отрубание кэша, переименование ссылок на стили мы уже пробовали. htaccess на сайте отсутствует, по причине того, что сервак работает под iis.

Проблема решилась неожиданным образом. Из-за нехватки места на диске админы перенесли сайты на другой сервер с винтом побольше, перебили ссылки в конфиге, но видимо не все. Блог на вордпрессе остался со старой ссылкой. Все обновления мы заливали на новый сервер, а сайт в сети отображался с копии на старом серваке. Поскольку база данных лежала на отдельном сервере, посты можно было публиковать с обоих копий. Так что причина проблемы в человеческом факторе.

Comment: Смешно. Тогда причём тут WordPress??? Вы должны знать / понимать карту боя. То есть как настроено, что подключено (логику работы), а потом уже пенять на то, что WP тупит. В 90% случаев тупят люди или плагины. Хотя да, в старых версиях, ну и иногда в новых я нахожу ошибки, чаще не критический (не мешающие работе), редко, единичные критические, конфликтные.  И да, 60% авторов плагинов не проверяют загружен ли тот или иной CSS/JS в других плагинах и пренебрегают необходимыми проверками, что порою и вызывает тормоза или конфликты. Ну и последнее IIS - Вы серьёзно? Не смешно.